# top ten customer by the amount they spend in Hiveql

Tags: count, group-by, hive, hiveql

i have 95904 rows(transactions) in a table `transaction_records` in hive

there are 9999 distinct customers
i want to know top ten customers by the amount they spend
I have the following fields:

```
txnno INT
txndate STRING
custno INT
amount DOUBLE
category STRING
product STRING
```

i tried using:

```
select custno, sum(amount) from (select txno, custno, amount, category, product from transaction_records group by custno);
FAILED: ParseException line 1:112 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting Identifier near ')' in subquery source
```

This doesnt work, I am new to hiveql do you know the query for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select custno, sum(amount) s from transaction_records group by custno order by s desc limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'collect_max' UDF in Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ) . This avoids a final sort of all your users.  (In your case, it might not be so bad, since there are only 10,000 customers, but for larger datasets it could be a problem )

```
SELECT collect_max( custno, amount, 10 )
FROM (
   SELECT custno, sum(amount) as amount
   FROM 
   transaction_records 
   GROUP BY custno ) tr;
```